# Run command not working? Applescript

Tags: performance, applescript

I originally have these codes

```html
set Chrome_List to {"Open Chrome", "Open Google Chrome", "Open GoogleChrome", "Open browser", "Open chrome"} --List of words, meaning "Good"

set TextEdit_List to {"Open Textedit", "Open Text Edit", "open text", "open empty text

"} --List of words, meaning "Bad"

set Gmail_List to {"Open Gmail", "Open Email", "open mail", "open Google Mail

", "open G-Mail"}

set photobooth_list to {"Open Photo Booth", "Open PhotoBooth", "open camera", "open Camera

", "open photo booth"}
set complete_list to Chrome_List & TextEdit_List & Gmail_List & photobooth_list

tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
 
 set theResponse to listen for complete_list with prompt "Which Application should I open"
 
 if (Chrome_List contains theResponse) then
  
  run script "/Volumes/Genesis/Application/GoogleChrome/GoogleChrome.scpt"
  
 else if (TextEdit_List contains theResponse) then
  
  run "/Volumes/Genesis/Application/TextEdit/TextEdit.scpt"
  
 else if (Gmail_List contains theResponse) then
  
  run "/Volumes/Genesis/Application/Gmail/Gmail.scpt"
 else if (photobooth_list contains theResponse) then
  
  run "/Volumes/Genesis/Application/PhotoBooth/PhotoBooth.scpt"
  
 end if
end tell
end
```

And that code links to this code:

```html
say "Opening Photo Booth"
launch application "Photo Booth"
end
end
end
```

But for some reason when I tell it to "Open PhotoBooth", it says: "/Volumes/Genesis/Application/PhotoBooth/PhotoBooth.scpt" doesn’t understand the “run” message.

This is also the same for Gmail, but other apps like GoogleChrome and TextEdit all work fine.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your scripts as apps instead of compiled scripts. Gmail.app vs Gmail.scpt

Also, change your command from "run" to "open".

```
do shell script "open '/Volumes/Genesis/Application/PhotoBooth/PhotoBooth.app'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. In the first occurrence you have:

```
run script "…
```

but in some of them you just have

```
run "…
```

You need run script. Also, in your second script I would suggest

```
tell application "Photo Booth" to activate
```

instead of using `launch` which ignores the on open event call (unless you're sure that's what you want).